# How to add additional text to invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, invoice, create-invoice

I'm currently working on magento 1.9 and wanted to add some additional text to invoice when we print in from admin panel like this :

[image]

As you can see above red numbers are the additional text for the invoice.

How do I do that in magento 1.9 ?
Please help me on this and I really appreciate if you show me step by step to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by creating the `Invoice.php` in the following path : 
`local/[Vendor]/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`.

```
class YouClass extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
{

    /**
     * @param Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @param  '??' $order
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _drawBottomText(Zend_Pdf_Page $page, $order)
    {
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);

        /* Getting the DPP */
        $Dpp = $order->getGrandTotal() / 1.1;
        $Ppn = $Dpp * 0.1; // dpp * 10%

        /* Convert the number to currency */
        $DppCurrency  =number_format($Dpp, 2, '.', ',');
        $PpnCurrency= number_format($Ppn, 2, '.', ',');
        $Currency = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();

        $page->drawText('DPP : ' . $Currency .' '. $DppCurrency,35,$this->y,'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText('PPN : ' . $Currency .' ' . $PpnCurrency,35,$this->y-20,'UTF-8');

        $page->drawText('Harga BKP sudah termasuk pajak',35,$this->y-40,'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText('PT KAYU RAYA INDONESIA',35,$this->y-55,'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText('Kawasan Industri dan Pergudangan Taman tekno BSD',35,$this->y-65,'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText('City Sektor XI Blok C No 2, Kota Tangerang Selatan',35,$this->y-75,'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText('NPWP: 76.406.266.7-411.000',35,$this->y-85,'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText('PKP: 76.406.266.7-411.000',35,$this->y-95,'UTF-8');

    }

    /**
     * Return PDF document
     *
     * @param  array $invoices
     * @return Zend_Pdf
     */
    public function getPdf($invoices = array())
    {
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

        $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
            }
            $page  = $this->newPage();
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();

            /* Add image */
            $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add address */
            $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add head */
            $this->insertOrder(
                $page,
                $order,
                Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID, $order->getStoreId())
            );
            /* Add document text and number */
            $this->insertDocumentNumber(
                $page,
                Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId()
            );
            /* Add table */
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
            /* Add body */
            foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item){
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
            /* Add totals */
            $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();
            }
            /* Add bottom text for details tax and company*/
            $this->_drawBottomText($page,$order);
        }
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;
    }
}
```

and register the class in your config.xml file in `etc` folder :

```
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>                    
                <order_pdf_invoice>YourClass</order_pdf_invoice>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
```

It is hard for me to adjust the text to match exactly like the screen shot, but this one displaying additional text and does the work.